# Intellij Diff and Merge tool on Cygwin

Tags: git, intellij-idea, cygwin, git-merge, git-diff

How can I configure git to use cygwin for diff and merge tool.

I can successfully call diff on command line at windows command prompt but not for cygwin.

Comment: Did you try to use `.sh` scripts from the Linux IDEA version?

Comment: Actually I checked it but it is not bundled with windows version.

Comment: True, your use case is not common, so you can just copy these files from the Linux version and adjust if necessary.

Comment: It seems that I found the root problem. I am starting intellij from task bar, but merge tool by cygwin. It seems there is a context issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have IntelliJ Idea started or not, it works. Follow the steps I described below.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of fiddling, I've found the following setup to work quite well in msysgit (so YMMV in Cygwin but I'm betting it will work there too).

Just place this in your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[diff]
    tool = intellij
[difftool "intellij"]
    cmd = cmd.exe //c "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.0/bin/idea.bat\" diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
[merge]
    tool = intellij
[mergetool "intellij"]
    cmd = cmd.exe //c "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.0/bin/idea.bat\" merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\""
```

No need for Linux IntelliJ's .sh scripts (which I don't think run properly in the more minimal msysgit environment anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing: running `IntelliJ Diff tool` from `Cygwin` without starting `IntelliJ Idea`, and having Git installed from Cygwin (not msysgit).

Managed to do this in the following way:

- Run the following command: `chmod +x idea.bat`
- Add "`...Intellij Idea/bin`" path to `Path` windows environment variable (restart Cygwin)
- Create the following script and put in `c:\cygwin\bin\` :

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> FILE1=`cygpath -w -a "$1"`  
> FILE2=`cygpath -w -a "$2"`  
> idea.bat diff $FILE1 $FILE2
> ```

- Edit the following in `.gitconfig` (as ytpete suggested):

```
[diff]
    tool = intellij
[difftool "intellij"]
    cmd = intellij_idea.sh $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

Hope, this will help somebody out there.